# Using form post versus get for opening sub pages?

Tags: php, forms, post, get

Is it good practice to use form post to send data to other pages versus just html link ($_GET) method.

Say if i have page **users.php** with all users of the site listed then i want to to page **user_details.php** that lists details about particular user - i can do it two ways.

```
<a href="user_details.php?user_id=752">Details</a>
```

or

```
<form action="user_details.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="742" />
<input type="button" name="nothing" value="User Details" />
</form>
```

or i could have code load every time that will put **$_POST** data into **$_SESSION** then on page **user_details.php** check **user_id** in **$_SESSION** is that even better security practice?

**EDIT:**  This site requires authentication before they can see anything. 
There only about 10 pages for admin total so i dont think they need to bookmark it.

Comment: There is no action in the form, how does your "link" work?

Comment: Ok forgot that part, its not the point of the question though

Comment: it's part of the point, without that, the form doesnt work

Comment: The use of `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` depends of the funcionality, if it's required use a form to edit the data, use $_POST, if the user can access directly to the page to read use $_GET

Comment: How can he direct access this means they need to know user ID, and if i do multiple admins then they can just change ID in the url and edit users that dont  belong to them.

Comment: The user id, is usually stored in the `$_SESSION` if you use a system login

Comment: I have admin_id in session users are the users of web site

Answer (score 1):

For web applications, to me, the basic guideline is:

- use GET for cases where you are not going to be modifying data (READ only)
- use POST for cases where you are modifying data (WRITE/UPDATE only)
- use POST for cases where you need to validate some data in order to return a variable result type (i.e. logins, contact forms, etc. where based on the data being sent, the behavior of the page returned can vary)

For typical web applications, there is also a consideration for whether you want a page/resource to be navigable with the data configuration.  In other words, do you want someone to be able to bookmark that page and see that same exact data representation (a data read). If so, use GET.

This also falls nicely in line with REST paradigms where the following HTTP actions are typically supported:

- GET -> read specified resources
- POST -> create a new data element on data resource
- PUT -> update an existing data element on resource
- DELETE -> delete an existing data element on resource

Comment: I'd like to be consistent with this. I already have $_POST everywhere, its just other designer we hired trying to say its not good practice.

Comment: @PetjaZaichikov Your other designer might be right depending on the use case. In fact, for the use case mentioned in your question, I would say you should use GET in the first approach.  Authentication of the requester to see the resource, should be a separate issue.

Comment: couldnt be better this explanation

Comment: Well its my site i did it way i like and as i said if i use GET then even entry level hacker/user can switch numbers in url and see users he does not supposed to see.

Comment: @PetjaZaichikov Then you have a very bad security model to begin with. You don't think a hacker could easily modify the hidden form field value?  Your user authentication and access restriction should be handled separately. Using GET vs. POST does absolutely nothing to protect access to the destination page.

Comment: At least it rules out wanna be hackers that dont know how to modify hidden value

Comment: And i just like it that way it looks cleaner than when you put variables in URL.

Comment: @PetjaZaichikov If anyone "wants to be" a hacker, I guarantee you they know how to modify a form field. It's is child's play.  You also make your site much less navigable to friendly users.  What if one of your friendly users wants to bookmark a page, or send a link to a page to another admin to look at an issue?  You are crippling your app because you don't have a real authentication/access system in place.

Comment: @PetjaZaichikov If you wanted clean URL's you could easily achieve this using server side rewrites. Any reasonably complex app done in the last 10 years probably uses this approach to give you a clean URL like `http://somedomain.com/user_details/1234` instead of `http://somedomain.com/user_details.php?user_id=1234`.  You seem to be making odd design choices to give you "functionality" that is better achieved through other approaches.

Comment: @PetjaZaichikov It is just crazy to think any moderately complex web application could get by with using only GET or only POST. You need both.

Answer (score 0):

One major benefit of using $_GET for this is that it allows your users to bookmark the url, essentially link to it instead of forcing the user to complete a form. If you use $_POST this isn't possible.

Using a querystring for this, however, isn't the most user friendly when it comes to URLs. It would be better to use some sort of pretty url structure like Wordpress does or Stackoverflow does for user pages. This can be done by editing your .htaccess file on your server.

Comment: I especially dont want no one bookmarking things because they need to authenticate before they will be able to use site first, its for the back end of site for admins.

Comment: So, for example if I use GET I can refresh the page and keep the data, but not with POST?  Sorry for the hijack...

Comment: You can refresh with post you just have to click resend form when dialog comes up. However there's no need to refresh currently.